# Image intersect

Tags: image, delphi, delphi-7, intersect

How do I know when my two images are intersecting?

Comment: You'll need to add more information than this to get a good answer.  Is there something within the images that we're testing for intersection?

Comment: Please give us more details on what you are talking about.

Comment: Please tag your question with the language and libraries you are working with.

Comment: "Delphi7" is all you need to know to determine the language. In fact, the term contains much more information than just "C" or "Visual Basic" would.

Comment: @Uwe - looking at 'revisions', when ninja left the comment there was only a `design` tag.

Comment: @Sertac - yes, but there was Delphi7 mentioned in the question. BTW, the comment I was responding to has vanished.

Comment: @Uwe - I see, thanks for clarifying! A fast moving target this one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get you right

```
function IsIntersertButNotContained(const R1, R2: TRect): Boolean;
var
  R: TRect;

begin
// R1 and R2 intersect
  Result:= IntersectRect(R, R1, R2)
//   R1 is not contained within R2
    and not EqualRect(R, R1)
//   R2 is not contained within R1
    and not EqualRect(R, R2);
end;
```

Comment: @Johan and @David: I explained why I edited the answer in code

Comment: @Johan The code speaks for itself. The answer is better without the comment. I made it so. +1

Comment: May be I'm wrong, but do we really need the UnionRect? If one rectangle is contained in the other, IntersectRect should return the inner rectangle and the checks for EqualRect should be enough.

Comment: @Uwe - Thank you, accepted. Just get accustomed to use UnionRect for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does a full check.

Next: usually a bitmap is not a rectangle.
Assuming you have a color assigned as 'transparent' say black *(RGB(0,0,0))*
You can see if the 2 bitmaps laying on top of each other have non-black pixels at the same x/y coordinate.

The following code demonstrates.
*I have not tested the code, so minor issues might be in there*

```
//This function first test the bounding rects and then goes into the pixels
//inside the overlaping rectangle.
function DoBitmapsOverlap(Bitmap1, Bitmap2: TBitmap; 
                          Bitmap2Offset: TPoint; TPColor: TColor): boolean;
var
  Rect1, Rect2: TRect;
  OverlapRect: TRect;
  x1,y1: integer;
  c1,c2: TColor;
begin
  Result:= false;
  Rect1:= Rect(0,0,Bitmap1.Width, Bitmap1.Height);
  with Bitmap2Offset do Rect2:= Rect(x,y,x+ Bitmap2.Width, y+Bitmap2.Height);
  if not(IntersectRect(OverlapRect, Rect1, Rect2)) then exit;
  for x1:= OverlapRect.Left to OverlapRect.Right do begin
    for y1:= OverlapRect.Top to OverlapRect.Bottom do begin
      c1:= Bitmap1.Canvas.Pixels[x1,y1];
      c2:= Bitmap1.Canvas.Pixels[x1-Bitmap2Offset.x, y1-Bitmap2Offset.y];
      Result:= (c1 <> TPColor) and (c2 <> TPColor);
      if Result then exit;            
    end; {for y1}
  end; {for x1}   
end;
```